# C++ when do you need to rebuild a program, if using a lib/dll?

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, to build C++ code.  I'm not using MFC or .net.  I have two projects, one is a DLL, and one is a program using that DLL to use classes and call functions on those classes.  So the program uses the .lib generated from the dll, and when running, has the DLL in the PATH.

So, my question is, under what circumstances, do I need to rebuild the program, if the DLL changes?

For example:
 - Change implementation of a function
 - Add a function
 - Delete a function
 - Add a private variable
 - Add a new isolated class

Comment: as long as declarations (the interface) don't change, you don't have to rebuild the program if the dll is chaging.

Comment: If you're using VS, the only *recompile* that should be required is upon changing the declaration header of the DLL (the program needs to be compiled with the new/changed/removed decls). Outside of that, a link-only-build of the program is all VS is going to do anyway, once the import lib changes after building  the DLL. And it is up to the task to make that determination if your project dependencies are configured correctly.

Comment: So if I add an exported function, I would need to rebuild the program accessing it?  Can someone get into more technical detail on the specifics.

Comment: @AberAber, yes if you add a function youhave to rebuild the project.